# Finding the line that is not parallel with others

Tags: linear-algebra

Find the line that is not parallel to the other three.

1. $x = (2,0) + t(1,1)$
2. $x = (1,2) + t(-1,1)$
3. $x = (1,1) + t(1,-1)$
4. $x = (1,3) + t(-1,1)$

Not sure how to approach this as I only know how to find parallel vectors. So how can I find parallel lines? Apparently, the line that is not parallel to the other three is option 1, which I believe is because of the point (1, 1) not being a scalar multiple of the others, but what about the other point?

Comment: You are on the right track. Lines are parallel iff their direction vectors are parallel. Direction vectors are parallel iff they are scalar multiples of each other.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From another perspective:
$$1) \quad  x = (2,0) + t(1,1) \Rightarrow (x,y)=(2+t,t) \Rightarrow y=x-2 \quad \quad \quad \  \\
2) \quad x = (1,2) + t(-1,1) \Rightarrow (x,y)=(1-t,2+t) \Rightarrow y=-x+3\\
3) \quad x = (1,1) + t(1,-1) \Rightarrow (x,y)=(1+t,1-t) \Rightarrow y=-x+2\\
4) \quad x = (1,3) + t(-1,1) \Rightarrow (x,y)=(1-t,3+t) \Rightarrow y=-x+4\\$$
The lines are parallel except the first as their slopes ($-1$) are equal.

Answer (score 3):

So parallel lines have the same "slope"

How can we generalize that? Well, for line 1, we go up $1$ on y-axis for every $1$ we go up on $x$-axis.

For the other three, we go down $1$ on the y-axis for every $1$ we go up on $y$-axis.

SO #1 is not parallel.

We can also see this because $(-1,1)$, $(1,-1)$, and $(-1,1)$ are all multiples of each other, so $(1,1)$ is the oddball.

Remember parallel means same slope so we're not concerned with the first term in each line expression.

Answer (score 3):

You have given a pair of straight lines in each line of text. The two vectors are given by
$$( u,v)+ t(a,b) $$

Parallelism depends on slope equality. So we can disregard first bracket in each case.

The *relative slope we can define* is then simply

$$\frac {dy/dt}{dx/dt}=b/a $$

Among the four choices the first has a relative slope $+1$ and the other three have $-1$

So the first choice is correct for parallelism.

Answer (score 1):

> Not sure how to approach this as I only know how to find parallel vectors.

Well, that is what this is really all about - checking if two vectors are parallel.

If you have two lines like

1. $(x, y) = (c1, d1) + t(a1,b1)$
2. $(x, y) = (c2, d2) + t(a2,b2)$

then $(a1,b1)$ and $(a2,b2)$ are direction vectors for the lines. If those direction vectors are parallel then the lines are parallel.

So simply calculate the determinant like

$a1 * b2 - b1*a2$

If result is zero the lines are parallel.